# Why are events from mat-dialog callback sent but not received?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a custom structural directive inside which I display a `MatDialog`.
In the dialog's `afterClosed()` an event is emitted.

The problem is that the event *is sent but not received* (`onHappened()` isn't called in the below example).
If I replace `... afterClosed()` with `of(true)`, all works well.

Why does this problem happen?
How can I fix it?

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icmc3k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.directive.ts). Some code snippets are below.

Directive usage in `menu-icons-example.html`

```html
...
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent>
    <ng-template appExample (happened)="onHappened()">
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>pause</mat-icon>
        <span>Pause</span>
      </button>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
...
```

`example.directive.ts`

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appExample]'
})
export class ExampleDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() readonly happened = new EventEmitter<void>();
  private condition = true;

  constructor(
    private readonly dialog: MatDialog,
    private readonly templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private readonly viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private readonly renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.condition) {
      const ref = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

      this.renderer.listen(ref.rootNodes[0], 'click', () => this.onClick());
    }
  }

  onClick(): void {
    this.dialog.open(DialogComponent).afterClosed()
    // of(void 0) works well
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.happened.emit();
      console.log('emitted');
    });
  }
```

Comment: It's not a structural directive, just a normal one (you don't need all the template refs stuff in there, check out my answer)

Comment: the directive shows its element only when `condition` is `true`. I.e. modifies DOM.
Therefore I thought it's a structural directive. Am I wrong?

Comment: A directive *can* modify DOM, but modifying a dom doesn't make a directive structural :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into an interesting situation where the menu is closed right after the dialog opens, and therefore the directive gets destroyed. Once it is destroyed, the event emitter is destroyed with it and no events can be issued. (**EDIT**: To be precise, the event emitter is not destroyed, but since the directive is, then the output connection from it to the outside world is removed.)

Check out your [forked StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icmc3k-6nha8a?file=src/app/example.directive.ts), I added a log in the directive's `ngOnDestroy` you can see that it is called right as the dialog opens.